# How to perform binary search on NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios, algorithm, nsarray, binary-search

What is the simplest way to do a binary search on an (already) sorted `NSArray`?

Some potential ways I have spotted so far include:

1. The use of `CFArrayBSearchValues` (mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFArrayRef/Reference/reference.html)) - would this work on an `NSArray`?
2. The method `indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:` of `NSArray` assumes the array is sorted and takes an `opts` param of type `NSBinarySearchingOptions` - does this mean it performs a binary search? The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) just say:

   > Returns the index, within a specified range, of an object compared with elements in the array using a given NSComparator block.
3. Write my own binary search method (something along the lines of [this](http://blog.mro.name/2010/01/binary-search-nsarray/)).

I should add that I am programming for iOS 4.3+

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use NSDictionary instead?  objectForKey: will search for you.

Comment: Couple of questions on that - what's the benefit of a dictionary over array for an object search? Also, in order to use the method you have suggested wouldn't I need to know the key of the object? The reason I am searching the array for the object in the first place is that I do not know its index - if I changed to a dictionary implementation then this means I wouldn't know the key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1 and 2 will both work. #2 is probably easier; it certainly doesn't make sense for that method to do anything other than a binary search (if the range is above a certain size, say). You could verify on a large array that it only does a small number of comparisons.

Comment: That's what I thought - the docs seem a little lacking in that they don't actually state it performs a binary search (they just heavily suggest). If I get around to doing the test you have suggested I'll be sure to post my results here.

Answer (score 17):

The second option is definitely the simplest. Ole Begemann has a blog entry on how to use the `NSArray`'s `indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:` method:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = ... // must be sorted
id searchObject = ...
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [sortedArray count]);
NSUInteger findIndex = [sortedArray indexOfObject:searchObject 
                                inSortedRange:searchRange
                                      options:NSBinarySearchingFirstEqual
                              usingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2)
                              {
                                  return [obj1 compare:obj2];
                              }];
```

See [NSArray Binary Search](http://oleb.net/blog/2013/07/nsarray-binary-search/)

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll have to make sure the findIndex is below [sortedArray count] if you use the findIndex later on. This will crash if the item does not exist and you try to fetch it using sortedArray[findIndex].

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised that nobody mentioned the use of [`NSSet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which [when it contains objects with a decent hash, such as most Foundation data types] performs constant time lookups. Instead of adding your objects to an array, add then to a set instead (or add them to both if you need to retain a sorted order for other purposes [or alternatively on iOS 5.0 or Mac OS X 10.7 there is [`NSOrderedSet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)]).

To determine whether an object exists in a set:

```
NSSet *mySet = [NSSet setWithArray:myArray]; // try to do this step only once

if ([mySet containsObject:someObject])
{
    // do something
}
```

Alternatively:

```
NSSet *mySet = [NSSet setWithArray:myArray]; // try and do this step only once

id obj = [mySet member:someObject];

// obj is now set to nil if the object doesn't exist or it is
// set to an object that "isEqual:" to someObject (which could be
// someObject itself).
```

It is important to know that you will lose any performance benefit if you convert the array to a set each time you do a lookup, ideally you will be using a preconstructed set containing the objects you want to test.

Comment: Yes indeed! this is very elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
//Method to pass array and number we are searching for.
- (void)binarySearch:(NSArray *)array numberToEnter:(NSNumber *)key{


    NSUInteger  minIndex = 0;
    NSUInteger  maxIndex = array.count-1;
    NSUInteger  midIndex = array.count/2;


    NSNumber *minIndexValue = array[minIndex];
    NSNumber *midIndexValue = array[midIndex];
    NSNumber *maxIndexValue = array[maxIndex];

    //Check to make sure array is within bounds
    if (key > maxIndexValue || key < minIndexValue) {
        NSLog(@"Key is not within Range");
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"Mid indexValue is %@", midIndexValue);

    //If key is less than the middleIndexValue then sliceUpArray and recursively call method again
    if (key < midIndexValue){
        NSArray *slicedArray = [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(minIndex, array.count/2)];
        NSLog(@"Sliced array is %@", slicedArray);
        [self binarySearch:slicedArray numberToEnter:key];

     //If key is greater than the middleIndexValue then sliceUpArray and recursively call method again
    } else if (key > midIndexValue) {
        NSArray *slicedArray = [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(midIndex+1, array.count/2)];
        NSLog(@"Sliced array is %@", slicedArray);
        [self binarySearch:slicedArray numberToEnter:key];

    } else {
      //Else number was found
        NSLog(@"Number found");
    }

}


//Call Method

@interface ViewController ()
@property(nonatomic)NSArray *searchArray;
@end


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
//Initialize the array with 10 values
    self.searchArray = @[@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8,@9,@10];

//Call Method and search for any number
    [self binarySearch:self.searchArray numberToEnter:@5];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`CFArrayBSearchValues` should work—`NSArray *` is [toll-free bridged](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html) with `CFArrayRef`.