# Objective-C Fastest Way to find Closest NSDate in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I pass in an NSDate to the following function and want to find the NSDate in the array that is closest in time to the passed in value.

Please note that I do not want to know if the array contains the exact date like this post:
[Find NSDate in sorted NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139459/find-nsdate-in-sorted-nsarray)

I want to know which date in the array is nearest in time to my reference date.

I must do this frequently. The following works but is slow - how can I speed things up?

```
// Get the XYZ data nearest to the passed time
- (eciXYZ)eciDataForTime:(NSDate*)time {

    // Iterate our list and find the nearest time
    float nearestTime = 86400; // Maximum size of dataset ( 2 days )
    int index = 0; // Track the index
    int smallestDifferenceIndex = index; // Track the index with the smallest index
    NSDate *lastListDate; // Track the closest list date
    for ( index = 0 ; index < [self.time count]-1 ; index++ ) {
        NSDate *listDate = [self.time objectAtIndex:index]; // Get the date - Time is an NSMutableArray of NSDates
        // NSTimeInterval is specified in seconds; it yields sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years.
        NSTimeInterval timeDifferenceBetweenDates = [listDate timeIntervalSinceDate:time];
        if ( timeDifferenceBetweenDates < nearestTime && timeDifferenceBetweenDates > 0 ) {
            nearestTime = timeDifferenceBetweenDates; // Update the tracker
            smallestDifferenceIndex = index; // Update the smallest difference tracker
            lastListDate = listDate; // Capture the closest date match
            //NSLog(@"Time: %f %@",timeDifferenceBetweenDates,listDate);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** I was under the mistaken impression that `NSMutableOrderedSet` would automatically maintain order. In the past I probably had used a subclass to achieve this effect. There is no benefit to using it over NSArray unless you want set semantics.

keeping a collection sorted is a good way to keep searches fast. <s>use `NSOrderedSet` or `NSMutableOrderedSet` instead of an array object if you can, otherwise</s> you will have to keep the array sorted when you add to it, or if it is only created once then you just sort it then.

Also you can enumerate any collection (that conforms to the protocol) faster by using `NSFastEnumeration`.

example:

```
// for an NSOrdered set or NSArray of NSDates
for (NSDate* date in self.times) {
    // do something with date
    // cleaner, shorter code too
}
```

because your collection is sorted you now will be able to tell what the closest date is without having to iterate the entire collection (most of the time).

```
// searching for date closest to Tuesday
[Sunday] <- start search here
[Monday] <- one day before
[Thursday] <- two days after, we now know that Monday is closest
[Friday] <- never have to visit
[Saturday] <- never have to visit
```

As pointed out by @davecom you can search faster using a binary search. Normally you would achieve this using either `CFArrayBSearchValues` or the `indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:` method on `NSArray` (it assumes the array is sorted so beware) and passing `NSBinarySearchingOptions` to the options parameter. In your case this won't work because you don't know the exact object or value you are looking for. You would have to roll your own binary search algorithm.

---

If this is not fast enough for your purposes we may need more information on context. It may be the best idea to use a C array/C++ list/NSPointerArray of timestamps instead. I feel like your biggest slowdown here is the Objective-C overhead, especially for the dates. If you don't use these as actual date objects anywhere then surely you would be better off using timestamps.

Comment: Using a set works if there can't be duplicate dates. Otherwise using an array works - just keep the array sorted as values are added.

Comment: @rmaddy thats true, but I didn't think that would apply in this case. not enough info to know if it does. Updated answer to reflect that, thanks.

Comment: Even faster would be to do a binary search through the sorted array rather than sequential as in your last example.

Comment: @davecom its certainly normal for that to be true, but in my experience with _small_ collections `NSFastEnumeration` outperforms binary search. updated answer with your note, thanks.

Comment: You'd have to keep a mutable ordered set sorted just the same as you would a mutable array, so I'm not sure why you're recommending the former over the latter.

Comment: `OrderedSet` just means it can have order but it won't sort elements for you automatically

Comment: @Caleb I'm not recommending either since I don't know the entire use case for the collection, but the `NSMutableCollection` is a set which may be desirable or not depending.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @BryanChen, I was mistaken. updating answer.

Comment: @Caleb yup, BryanChen already pointed that out and I've already edited the answer. I think I must have used a subclass to achieve this effect previously. Thanks.

Comment: Right -- I saw his comment once I saved mine and the page refreshed.